# Unit test for a disabled timer

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

I have a component which regularly calls a function using a timer. From the outside I can configure the rate for that timer.

Testing this is basically trivial: Set up the timer, wait some time, count the calls to the function, and compare to what you expected.

Now there is also the option to disable the timer. How could I test for that?

Waiting for time x is not enough, as the timer may call at x+1.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: do you use your own timer or some existing implementation?

Comment: An existing one, actually it's the `setInterval` function from JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't try to test functionality of your language. if js provides you method `setInterval` then assume it works. what you should test that if your code calls `setInterval` properly. i don't know much about js testing but if you can, just mock it and check if it was called. if you can't mock it then use one more level of indirection. create your own wrapper for timer - without any logic, just passing invocations. then, in tests, you can check if that wrapper was called or not. i would avoid using wait/sleep in tests

Comment: I don't want to test the `setInterval` function, I want to test whether it was configured using a specific interval time (or, in my special case, not at all).

Comment: so again: if js API allows you to check if setInterval was configured/called then do it directly without waiting for registered function to be triggered. if not, then create your own layer for registering callback functions and test if this layer was configured/called properly